# How to update Android app programmatically?

Tags: android, updates

I have developed an Android app for a client so that I am not putting the app in the play-store. How can I update the app? How the update function is working on another apps?

Answer (score 2):

Before uploading the Apk of your app to playstore, you have to create a signed certificate of your app and then build your apk with that signed certificate each time you upload the updated version of your app. And yes don't forget to increase the version code and version name of the app in your manifest file.

How to create a certificate:
Right click on project go to Android Tools->Export signed certificate (if you have not created yet then create it and if you have already created it use the existing and build the apk and upload on play store ) and don't forget to save that certificate somewhere otherwise you will not able to update your app.

Manifest file:

```
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0"
```

Whenever you make any changes to your code and want to update it on playstore, increase the version code and change the version name and build it using existing signed certificate

Comment: Sir I know How to create signed build. "I am not putting the app in the play-store"

Comment: If you don't have the signed key, you simply cannot update the app. There is no "programming way" to do this. That's the whole point of key. Anyone can get access to the code easily. so key is to provide a private key that unlocks this feature :)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is no update function in-apps. When you publish an App in the Google Play Store the store itself is the one who manage the updates. So when you upload a second version of your app, it sends this new version to all the users who have it in their devices.